# Resharper chained method calls indentation

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a code like this and I want Resharper to reformat such code always in this way

```
using (var testSystem = await new TestSystemBuilder()
    .WithSomething(TestData.Something)
    .WithSomethingElse(TestData.Something)
    .Build())
{
}
```

But after Resharper reformatting it makes it look like this:

```
using (var testSystem = await new TestSystemBuilder()
                            .WithSomething(TestData.Something)
                            .WithSomethingElse(TestData.Something)
                            .Build())
{
}
```

How to force it to keep one tab indentation for chained calls?
Resharper version: 2017.3.2

**Update**: it actually happens only for async calls...

Comment: Without actually answering your question, but have you tried selecting that block of code, then hit Alt+Enter and `Format Selection | Configure...` ? That should give you only the options that are affecting the current selection.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you, didn't know about this possibility, is definitely helpful, but the grid is empty in this case

Answer (score 1):

`ReSharper` -> `Options` -> `Code Editing` -> `C#` -> `Formatting Style` -> `Tabs, Indents, Alignment` -> `Align Multiline Constructs` -> Uncheck `Chained method calls`

Comment: this is not the one I need. it's about aligning next chained calls to a dot of the first one, and it's unchecked

Comment: could you update your question with a code snippet of your desired result? that would help understand exactly what you are shooting for.